# pgAdmin IV "'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 8773: character maps to <undefined>"

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'm using pgAdmin IV (version 5.7) now because of my job, previously I only had used pgAdmin III.
My problem is that I have already set the charset correctly with

```sql
set client_encoding = 'Win1252';
```

and when I execute a select, this error still appears. I'm connected to the same database with both, and the database I'm linking to is Postgres 9.5. When I do the same with pgAdmin III, I get all the data correctly.

When I run `show server_encoding` on the database I receive ***WIN1252**:
[image: Server encoding WIN1252]

Error:

> 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 8773: character
> maps to <undefined>

Comment: This needs more information 1) The complete version information for pgAdmin4 2) The Postgres version you are connecting to. 3) Are you connecting to the same database with `pgAdmin4` as with `pgAdmin3` 4) What does `show server_encoding;` return?

Comment: Edited with the suggested pieces of information, thank you!

Comment: What are you doing when you receive the error? Can you connect with `psql` and not receive an error?

Comment: I'm receiving this error only when I execute a select. Sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: What is the select and do you have any issues when you do the select in `psql`?

Comment: The select is ```select * from ws.ws_log order by id desc limit 100;``` and I have no issues when I do the select in `psql`

Comment: Hmm, I just tried here and ran into similar issue. I set the `client_encoding` under the *Parameters* tab of the database *Properties* and it seemed to ignore that setting. I'm thinking you will need to file an issue here [pgAdmin4 issues](https://www.pgadmin.org/support/issues/). FYI, you will need to set up a Postgres community account to get to the issues page itself.

Comment: [Issue #7491](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/7491) created, any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Use `psql`, you will get a lot more done.